# How to set JScrollPane Background transparent and JScrollBarr Visible with JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7pOE.png]

What I tried:

1. `jTextArea.setOpaque(false);` this makes `JTextArea` transparent.
2. `jScrollPane.setOpaque(false);` this gives **no effect**
3. then I tried this which hides both `JScrollPane` and `JTextArea`.

   ```
   jScrollPane.getViewPort().setOpaque(false); 
   jScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
   ```
4. then I tried this which hides both `JScrollPane` and `JTextArea`.

   ```
   jScrollPane.setViewPort(new MyViewPort());
   class MyViewPort() extends JViewPort{
       public MyViewPort(){
           setOpaque(false);
       }
   }
   ```

What I want to achieve is `JScrollPane` background transparent and transparent `JTextArea` where I should able to add text and visible `JScrollPane`.

**Update:**
I did like this I can add text in textArea but the jscrollPane is not transparent:

```
public class TransparentBackground extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TransparentBackground() {
        jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        lblBackground = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jTextArea.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane.setViewportView(jTextArea);
        jScrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        jScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        jTextArea.setOpaque(false);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 40, 580, 300));

        lblBackground.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bg.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(lblBackground, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 680, 390));

        pack();
    }
```

And When I use

```
jScrollPane.setViewPort(new MyViewPort());
class MyViewPort() extends JViewPort{
    public MyViewPort(){
        setOpaque(false);
    }
}
```

Both textArea and JScrollPane disappears(transparent) but need jTextArea transparent and editable or can add text in it.

[When I set custom view port result is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7n1n.png)

Comment: If everything is non-opaque, then it should work fine. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Yah It is working but the I can not add text in jTextArea. That is my problem..

Comment: Then provides us with a demonstrable example of it not work ... cause I have half a dozen examples which do

Comment: please check example.

Comment: if you have half dozen working example then can you please give it to me.

Comment: `I can not add text in jTextArea` - changing the opaque property of a component does not affect the ability to add text to the component. You have some problem with your code which is why you need to post a "SSCCE". `please check example.` - the code you posted uses 3rd party API's and does not compile. Therefore it is NOT a "SSCCE". Post a demo that uses API's from the base JDK only. There is no need to use 3rd party API's to make a component non-opaque. Post a proper "SSCCE" that we can compile an execute if you need more help.

Comment: Yes, You are right it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whats wrong with privious code, may be due to the use of drag and drop. 
Here is code that worked. Thank you **Camickr** and **MadProgrammer** for you suggestion. :)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TransparentBackground1 extends JFrame {
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblBackground;

    public TransparentBackground1() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(675, 375));
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        jTextArea = new JTextArea();
        lblBackground = new JLabel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        jTextArea.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane.setViewportView(jTextArea);

        //Code To make transparent
        jScrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        jScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        jTextArea.setOpaque(false);


        lblBackground.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bg.png"))); // NOI18N

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TransparentBackground().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Here is Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfAJf.png)